# How to loop data from a table in sql server and using the returned data to query another table. Please see

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

This is what I am trying to achieve :

I have a table in a database in which there is a column named "item_code".

I need to query this table, returning ONE row at a time. Now, I need to use the value of the column "item_code" for the one row which has been returned to query ANOTHER table where I'll use it to fetch a bunch of row(s). How do I do this?

I tried using a datareader object in a while loop, fetch one row at a time and then query the other table inside this loop to fetch the rows required but I couldn't figure out how to put this data in a gridview (use datatable? if yes, how?) in such a way that the previous rows in the gridview don't get erased after each iteration of the while loop.

The only way I know for putting data into a gridview is by using .Fill() but obviously, Fill method wouldn't do in this case as it would wipe out the previous entries in the gridview.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will work, but you are correct, Fill() will erase the contents of the table. Instead, use Merge()

```
var myMainTable = new DataTable();

foreach(var itemId in itemIds)
{
  var currentTable = new DataTable();
  // submit new query
  myAdapter.Fill(currentTable)
  myMainTable.Merge(currentTable);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to query this table, returning ONE row at a time. Now, I need to use the value of the column "item_code" for the one row which has been returned to query ANOTHER table where I'll use it to fetch a bunch of row(s). How do I do this?

You could use a single SQL query that joins the two tables on "item_code" and retrieves the results from the second table.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in SQL level in one step, like this:

```
SELECT Table2.* 
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.item_code = Table2.item_code
ORDER BY Table2.item_code
```

And of course if you need to make a smaller list, you can wirte the `WHERE` too.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is, I guess, the proper and semantic way of achieving what I wanted to do. But i chose the other one as the answer because I had to choose one. :)